# Retrieve each product bought by a customer MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am working on a homework assignment for a database class.  Part of the assignment is creating SQL queries to accomplish various tasks using the following database:

```
create database homework3;
use homework3;

create table customer(
    cus_code int, 
    cus_lname varchar(20), 
    cus_fname varchar(20), 
    cus_initial char, 
    cus_areacode int, 
    cus_phone int, 
    primary key(cus_code));

create table invoice(
    inv_number int, 
    cus_code int, 
    inv_date date, 
    primary key(inv_number), 
    foreign key(cus_code) references customer(cus_code));

create table vendor(
    vend_code int, 
    vend_name varchar(30), 
    vend_contact varchar(30), 
    vend_areacode int, 
    vend_phone int, 
    primary key(vend_code));

create table product(
    prod_code int, 
    prod_desc varchar(50), 
    prod_price int, 
    prod_quant int, 
    vend_code int, 
    primary key(prod_code), 
    foreign key(vend_code) references vendor(vend_code));

create table line(
    inv_number int, 
    prod_code int, 
    line_units int, 
    primary key(inv_number, prod_code), 
    foreign key(inv_number) references invoice(inv_number), 
    foreign key(prod_code) references product(prod_code));

/* cus_code, cus_lname, cus_fname, cus_initial, cus_areacode, cus_phone */
insert into customer values (10010, "Ramas", "Alfred", 'A', 615, 8442573);
insert into customer values (10011, "Dunne", "Leona", 'K', 713, 8941238);
insert into customer values (10012, "Smith", "Kathy", 'W', 615, 8942285);
insert into customer values (10013, "Olowski", "Paul", 'F', 615, 2221672);
insert into customer values (10014, "Orlando", "Myron", NULL, 615, 2971228);

/* inv_number, cus_code, inv_date */
insert into invoice values (1001, 10011, '2008-08-03');
insert into invoice values (1002, 10014, '2008-08-04');
insert into invoice values (1003, 10012, '2008-03-20');
insert into invoice values (1004, 10011, '2008-09-23');

/* vend_code, vend_name, vend_contact, vend_areacode, vend_phone */
insert into vendor values (232, "Bryson", "Smith", 615, 2233234);
insert into vendor values (235, "SuperLoo", "Anderson", 615, 2158995);

/* prod_code, prod_desc, prod_price, prod_quant, vend_code */
insert into product values (12321, "hammer", 189 ,20, 232);
insert into product values (65781, "chain", 12, 45, 235);
insert into product values (34256, "tape", 35, 60, 235);
insert into product values (12333, "hanger", 200 ,10, 232);

/* inv_number, prod_code, line_units */
insert into line values (1001, 12321, 1);
insert into line values (1001, 65781, 3);
insert into line values (1002, 34256, 6);
insert into line values (1003, 12321, 5);
insert into line values (1002, 12333, 6);
```

And the statement in question is:

[image: Query]

I tried:

```
use homework3;
select product.prod_desc, customer.cus_fname, customer.cus_lname from product, 
customer 
natural join line where line.inv_number is not null;
```

which returned absolutely wrong results with every person having bought several of each product.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Incidentally, phone numbers are really strings. They may only contain integers, but that's just a quirk of design. You can tell that they're not really numbers because you'd never subtract one phone number from another.

Comment: And we stopped joining tables this way back in 1992, which makes me wonder a little...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the joining conditions between `line` and the other tables. You need to include the `invoice` table to get the relationship to the customer.

```
SELECT cus_fname, cus_lname, prod_desc
FROM customer AS c
JOIN invoice AS i ON c.cus_code = i.cus_code
JOIN line AS l ON l.inv_number = i.inv_number
JOIN product AS p ON p.prod_code = l.prod_code
ORDER BY cus_code
```

Get out of the habit of using implicit joins (`FROM customer, product`), list each table you're joining specifically with an ANSI `JOIN` with the appropriate `ON` condition.

Comment: Awesome.  This is exactly what I needed.  I have gone back and re-wrote my other queries now as well and they are much more readable and logical.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you removed the `natural join` from your query, you would have a cross-product of products and customers: matching each product with each customer.  Adding the join just matches irrelevant info to each pairing.

Instead, what you want is every row in `line` (which I presume is a purchase) joined with the corresponding customer & product so you can get the desired fields about each.

Comment: Right.  each customer has a `cus_code` which gets linked with an `inv_number` in `invoice`, then `inv_number` and `prod_code` get linked in the table `line`  meaning I should be able to get the names and descriptions of who bought what?